# Why the same code give different result in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

```
window.scope = 'global'
Object.prototype.scope = 'object proto'

console.log(scope);
```

I'm writing above simple script to test the scope, but I got different result in chrome dev tools and jsfiddle.

- chrome: 'object proto';
- jsfiddle: 'global';

Why?

Comment: Interesting. But what's the actual thing you're trying to do? I assume you know better than to extend `Object.prototype` with an enumerable property, that this is some sort of thought experiment...

Comment: In any case, the result you get [in a real environment](http://jsbin.com/aniqurUh/1) (e.g., like the fiddle you didn't link, as opposed to dev tools) is the correct result. I'm not entirely surprised to find the occasional oddity in dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I paste your code into a new HTML document and view in Chrome, I get `global` printed to the console when the page is loaded.

When you paste your code into the DevTools console *directly*, you get:

```
object proto
undefined
```

And that is because what the DevTools actually evaluates is the following script (in my case):

```
with ((console && console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
  window.scope = 'global'
  Object.prototype.scope = 'object proto'

  console.log(scope);
}
```

So, by using the `with` statement, the `console` is added to the current scope chain which *binds* the `scope` variable to it. Since you're extending the object prototype before accessing the `scope`, you see the result of your operation when referencing `scope` (which actually refers to `console.scope`, thanks to `with` statement).

The reason why there' two lines of output is obvious: first, the `console.log` gets executed and so the message is printed onto the console, then the DevTools gives you the result of the expression `console.log` which is *nothing* (the function doesn't have a return value).

Hope this clarifies things a bit for you.